# Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value

Tags: c#, html

> Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ff' to data type int. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at MyApp.WebForm1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\myProjectFiles\MyApp\MyApp\Registration.aspx.cs:line 48 ClientConnectionId:a7f5710d-3f9e-4cd9-bf01-49ad3fd8cec4

Comment: You need to ***URGENTLY*** read (and **embrace!!**) [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ff' to data type int.
```

Just what your error says, failed conversion in your SQL query.  Its hard to say where in your query the issue is at without seeing the query.